# Google O-Auth 2.0 - Is it possible to authenticate a user without opening in a browser window?

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-photos-api

I am currently developing a java command-line tool without a graphical interface, which requires little to no mouse interaction by the user. The ideal flow would be for a user to access their Google Photos/Drive without having to deal with the entire browser authentication flow *(therefore will not be using a service account).*

I am rather new to incorporating the Google O-Auth 2.0, and I have come across how

 - Client Login is depreciated, so no user/password like flows

 - Embedded browsers OAuth requests are also blocked

 - I can use a refresh token, but it still requires the browser flow for the first time

I have currently been working with O-Auth version for installed apps, but I was wondering if there was any way to do so within the application alone (no redirecting to a new tab or programmatic authentication)?

Comment: [Possibly useful](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred).

Comment: Also, [this utility might work](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) (have not tried it).